# Permanent Histogram Stretch with QGIS or FWTools

Tags: qgis, fwtools, histogram

Is there a way to permanently stretch a histogram of a raster within QGIS or gdal?  I would like to stretch a satellite image with a Standard Deviation 2.5 stretch.  I would prefer to use QGIS or FWTools, but I am open to other open source tools.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

A great and easy way to stretch the histogram of a raster seems to be gdal_contrast_stretch:

https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts/wiki/Gdal-contrast-stretch

Installation guide: https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts

Then you can use it as

```
gdal_contrast_stretch -linear-stretch <target_average value> 2.5
 <input-raster.tif> <stretched-raster.tif>
```

That is, you also have to indicate the target average value. Supposing you only have one band, a (not so elegant but working) way on Unix to find out the mean (saved in a variable $mean) is:

```
mean=$(gdalinfo -stats <input-raster.tif> |grep Mean|cut -f4 -d "="|sed 's/, StdDev//g')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have used OpenEV from FWTools for that purpose. Open the image - apply LUT stretch - save image with original resolution into new image file. FWTools is pretty old but try if if still works for you. OpenEV is also available from OSGeo4W.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am aware of OpenEV. I want to be able to do this from within QGIS, or with gdal (FWTools). I am trying to reduce the number of software packages I use, and eliminate the need of jumping in and out of software.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand that you was meaning just GDAL. FWTools, by its own words "includes OpenEV, GDAL, MapServer, PROJ.4 and OGDI as well as some supporting components" http://fwtools.maptools.org/.

Comment: My mistake. I will edit it the post

Comment: Gdalinfo -stats computes statistics. Here is an example of the report:

 Metadata:
   STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
   STATISTICS_MEAN=75.570955180556
   STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
   STATISTICS_STDDEV=31.050844340168

By mean and stddev you can calculate the desired range and use that in gdal_translate -scale. Read the usage from http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html. You will need a newer GDAL version than FWTools contains but you should find GDAL 1.10 from your QGIS 2.x installation and Gisinternals.com/sdk delivers nightly GDAL builds for Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I have gdal 1.9 I believe. Will this make it a perm histogram stretch?

Comment: If you re-scale your image with -scale option the new file will be permanently stretched. I have used the option only occasionally for making some 16-bit or 32-bit DEMs suitable for visual inspection. Often they are all too dark otherwise.